# Open File with non default program

Tags: java, file, desktop

I want to make a java program witch automatically 
opens a specified program to a given file
for example a mp4 file should be opened with a Converter to convert it to avi

So my question is:
is it possible to open a file in java with a given program, but not the default one?
And if yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean, as other answerers here apparently understand your question, that you want to write a Java program that runs some other program to open a particular file? Or do you mean that you want to make your Java program the default "open" program for a certain file type, so anytime someone double-clicks a file of that type in the directory, your program runs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you know the exact path or the program has a known envirment variable, it's quite easy:

```
try
{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad Q:/Test/tmp.txt");
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    stdInput.close();
}
catch(Exception k)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, k.getMessage());
}
```

This opens the file tmp in notepad.

Comment: The BufferedReader there is just a remnant from an old code bit I had, you don't actually need that, Just the Process line.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any program you want with any file you want with Process.exec()

(Actually getting it to open the default program is trickier IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `Runtime.exec()` method, but you **must** read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) beforehand. The program that you want to run must accept a exec parameter that represent the file to be opened.

I know that this is not an answer for you question, but if you want to open a file using the default application (registered by the OS) you should use the "open" method of `java.awt.Desktop` class.

Comment: Note that using a `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process` helps to implement at least one of the recommendations of the linked article (merge the streams and it is easier to consume them). +1 for being the only one to mention the article that the OP ***will need to read*** if going down this path.